# How to run jupyter notebook behind haproxy and make its content public?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy

How to run `jupyter notebook` behind `haproxy`? I tried to find an answer on the Internet but there are solutions only for `Ngix` and `Apache` and I think that using `haproxy` as a reverse proxy can be even a simple solution that does not involve creating special Virtual servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution run successfully and also does load balancing.

Assuming that you have a site `jupyter.example.com` the following code inserted in the /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg will solve your problem of making the jupyter notebook public:

```
backend jupyter
        option forwardfor
        http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]
        reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /mez/(.*) \1\ /\2
        reqadd X-Script-Name:\ /jupyter
        option http-server-close
        server Server12 10.0.0.12:8888 weight 40 check
        server Server14 10.0.0.14:8888 weight 20 check
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer! It worked out for me for `jupyter.example.com`. However, for my usecase I would like to use something like `jupyter.example.com/workspace1` and that should redirect to a Jupyter notebook running on the system. However the request is being redirected to `10.0.0.12:8888/workspace1` which jupyter is unable to resolve and gives a 404. Do you know how to go about that?

Comment: Can you post your haproxy log?  The problem is that jupyter is listening on aport on that machine and you cannot configure an URL as you do on a webserver.  In this case, you could create multiple backends, one for each of your workspace which will be redirected by string parsing in your frontend section.. Please let me know if that works for you

Comment: Hey I was a little confused about how ACLs work on the URI. In my frontend configuration, I had asked to redirect if the path ended with `/workspace1` but what I really wanted was to redirect on path beginning as jupyter automatically appends /tree to the end. I changed the configuration and it worked. Thanks for your answer, the backend configuration you put out saved me days of research!